# How to pass variable from a joint mysql query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I'm trying to join 2 tables with the same id and same username to check if the row exists. With the query, I use I always get the Undefined variable: query from my view.

I'm using this query:

```
$query= DB::table('table1')->select('table1.id')
->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')
->where('active','=','1', 'username','=',Auth::user()->name)->get();
return view('table1', ['table1' => $query]);
```

Please note that without the joint query it works fine. Same variable name and I can get the ID from table1.

Now I'm not really good at joining 2 tables so I might have an error somewhere in there or my return view is wrong. Without the joint query, I use the same return view as with joins. Maybe that's the problem.

EDIT: I was passing old variable from my old query along. Forgot to close it. Now it passes the variable. Only need to figure the right join query now.

Comment: Have u tried left join ?

Comment: I did. Same problem.

Comment: can u try my answer, and please show the table structure of both the tables?

Comment: can u add table names before active and username, for example table1.active , or table2.active and try.

Comment: Did try that too.

Comment: Sorry guys. Figured it out. I was passing 2 variables from the same controller. Switching from a query with 1 table to a joint query I left an old return view opened. Closed it now and it passes the variable. Now the query is wrong but I'll try to use one of the queries posted here. Main problem is fixed so thank you all for your answers.

Comment: great :) you figured it out, next time please post full code so we can get where the exact error is, sometime the error would be somewhere and we would be trying to decode somewhere else :P

Answer (score 0):

The join query u used will only show value/data only both the table has data in it to display, at the same time if u use left join it will display even if there is no data available in the next table or the second table you are trying to access.

```
$query= DB::table('table1')
->leftJoin('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')
->where('active','=','1')
->where('username','=',Auth::user()->name)
->select('table1.id')
->get();

if($query) // this means there is data in $query
{
    return view('table1', ['table1' => $query]);
} else { // there is no data in $query
    return view('table1', ['table1' => "no data available"]);
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. And the query is not empty since it won't even return the "no data available"

Comment: what does it return ?

Comment: Undefined variable: query again

Comment: thats strange can u show us the complete code of that function may be somewhere something has gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can easy to join two table using leftJoin. Try this code.

```
$query = DB::table('table1')
    ->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.id')
    ->where('active','=','1', 'username','=',Auth::user()->name)->get();
     return view('table1', ['table1' => $query]);
```

Comment: Still the same. I've tried leftjoin and still nothing. I've also added table1.active and table2.username which I forgot before. Still nothing changed.

Comment: `use App\your_model_name;` are u import your model?

Answer (score 0):

try using like this.

```
$query= DB::table('table1')->select('table1.id')
->join('table2','table2.id','=','table1.id')
->where(['table1.active'=>'1', 'table1.username'=>Auth::user()->name])->get();
return view('table1', ['table1' => $query]);
```